# How much should a react frontend application be automated tested?

Tags: architecture, testing, react

I'm backend developer working on a very backend heavy application. So most of the business logic is writen in the backend. In our project we are considering a full rewrite of the frontend. Currently the frontend code is extremely messy and refactoring stuff takes forever. There are no tests.

I'm not a frontend developer eventhough I have made some contributions to the code and have a good overview on how the current code looks like. In the backend we have really good experience with writing test driven development. So I naturally through the some should be true for frontend development. But looking at from the perspective that the frontend is mainly visualizing data and calling rest api's to invoke business logic. I'm considered if a strict test driven approach would be very cumbersome, with a lot of mock objects and allot testing overhead.

What are your experiences how much should you test? What do you do in your daily job and how does it work for you?

Comment: If you're starting out now building the application from scratch then you have the opportunity to take decisions which would avoid mock objects and ensure unit tests are quick and easy to write.   For example, splitting the UI into small, 'pure' visual components.  Also consider Redux to manage state and avoid coupling to REST APIs or anything else which might be cumbersome to mock.

Comment: Thanks Ben. Using a redux state to limit the interactions with the backend makes very much sense for my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always the answer is "it depends".

I would always apply Unit Tests to Business Logic. but also in most cases for other "logic" things, like data mapping, hand made filters, etc etc.

I would always try to split my app into smart and dumb components. A simple visual component is "dumb". It just gets data and shows it (for example a table), it just let the user enter data and provides this data to the parent component. Or in some cases both (for example the user can enter their age, the input is send to a parent component and the parent decides that the age is not valid, from a business perspective, and send the error information back, so that the dumb component can now show the corresponding message)

Then you have Unit tests that will check logic (in the smart components) and Unit tests that focus on visuals (dumb component).

To avoid mocks, the components could primarily communicate over the state (redux). Then you only need to mock the state. To tell the truth, that has some other drawbacks, because  moving all information, even the simplest ones, over the state could be stressfull too.

Personaly i would test the smart and the dumb components, but quite often the budget is tight and then i would reduce the coverage of the "visual" unit tests. Not because its not necessary, but its a bit less likely to create errors there and they are more easily found by human testers. It still a bad thing to do, but with limited budget there are some consequences.

In some projects we go the other way, there we have special "styling" unit tests to ensure that the design has no regressions.

As always depends on the project, the priorities, the team setup, ...

Think about where your priorites are. Think about the capabilites of your team. Think about the cost of errors in the production.
As an example if you just build an application for a small set of users, then visuals may be less important in comparison to functionality. If you build an application that represents a company to the world, then visuals, styling, etc suddenly is much more important.

warm regards
Jan

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to make this answer. I learned allot

Answer (score 2):

In general, I don't automate the testing of UI.  But maybe that's because I've always worked on small teams where there isn't an army of people or the available time to set up stuff like this.

What I do instead is push as much code functionality as I can out of the UI and into supporting classes, like the View Model and the Model objects, where they can be routinely unit-tested in the usual way, without requiring UI automation.

Comment: Exactly this. Push what needs testing into code that's easy to test, which usually isn't the UI.